# Reach DataTemplate element from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have this code (a part of a big XAML file):

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Name="R1"/>
                <Rectangle Name="R2" Tapped="RTEventHandler"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I'd like to change the backgorund of the R1 rectangle when R2 is tapped, so I need to reach R1 from the CodeBehind. I tried to give x:Name for the elements but it didn't help.

Thx for the help

Comment: try `(Rectangle)this.FindName("R1")`

Comment: Does [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579(v=vs.110).aspx) help you out?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you bind the color of the Rectangle rather than trying to find a UI element.
Change your xaml to

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Name="R1" Fill="{Binding FirstBackground}"/>
        <Rectangle Name="R2" Tapped="RTEventHandler"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The tap event would then get the DataContext of the tapped element and set the FirstBackground

```
var viewModel = (sender as Rectangle).DataContext as MyViewModel;
viewModel.FirstBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

Make sure your MyViewModel class implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

[How to access a named control inside a XAML DataTemplate](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html)

Comment: Just a link is bad, please post code and then add link for reference.